# sqlalchemy how to generate (many-to-many) relationships with automap_base

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

As a background: I'm creating an ORM based on a schema of an already existing database. - This due to the fact that the python application won't be the "owner" of said database.

Now in this database there is a table called "`task`" and a table called "`task_notBefore__task_relatedTasks`" - this latter is a many-to-many relation between different entries in the "`task`" table.

now `automap_base()` has an automated detection of these relationships as described [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#many-to-many-relationships). However this fails for my case, and no relationship is being build.

I then try to manually create the relationship:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import generate_relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, interfaces, relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class DBConnection:
    def __init__(self, connection_url, **kwargs):
        self.engine = create_engine(connection_url, **kwargs)
        self._Base = automap_base()

        self._Base.prepare(self.engine, reflect=True)

        self.Task = self._Base.classes.task
        self.Order = self._Base.classes.order
        self.Poller = self._Base.classes.poller

        rel = generate_relationship(self._Base, interfaces.MANYTOMANY, relationship, 'related', self.Task, self.Task,
                                    secondary=self._Base.classes.task_notBefore__task_relatedTasks, backref='notBefore')

        self._Session = sessionmaker()
        self._Session.configure(bind=self.engine)

        self.session = self._Session()
```

However this still doesn't "do" anything: it doesn't add anything to the `self.Task` "class".

How would one do this?

Answer (score 5):

The primary problem in this case is not just the many-to-many relationship, but the fact that it's a self-referential, many-to-many relationship. Because `automap` is simply translating the mapped class names to relationship names, it constructs the same name, e.g. `task_collection`, for both directions of the relationship, and the naming collision generates the error. This shortcoming of `automap` feels significant in that self-referential, many-to-many relationships are not uncommon.

Explicitly adding the relationships you want, using your own names, won't solve the problem because `automap` will still try to create the `task_collection` relationships. To deal with this issue, we need to override `task_collection`.

If you're okay with keeping the name `task_collection` for the forward direction of the relationship, we can simply pre-define the relationship--specifying whatever name we want for the `backref`. If `automap` finds the expected property already in place, it will assume the relationship is being overridden and not try to add it.

Here's a stripped down example, along with the an `sqlite` database for testing.

### Sqlite Database

```
CREATE TABLE task (
    id INTEGER, 
    name VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE task_task (
    tid1 INTEGER,
    tid2 INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(tid1) REFERENCES task(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(tid2) REFERENCES task(id)
);

-- Some sample data
INSERT INTO task VALUES (0, 'task_0');
INSERT INTO task VALUES (1, 'task_1');
INSERT INTO task VALUES (2, 'task_2');
INSERT INTO task VALUES (3, 'task_3');
INSERT INTO task VALUES (4, 'task_4');

INSERT INTO task_task VALUES (0, 1);
INSERT INTO task_task VALUES (0, 2);

INSERT INTO task_task VALUES (2, 4);
INSERT INTO task_task VALUES (3, 4);

INSERT INTO task_task VALUES (3, 0);
```

Putting it into a file called `setup_self.sql`, we can do:

```
sqlite3 self.db < setup_self.sql
```

### Python Code

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

DeclBase = declarative_base()

task_task = Table('task_task', DeclBase.metadata,
                  Column('tid1', Integer, ForeignKey('task.id')),
                  Column('tid2', Integer, ForeignKey('task.id')))

Base = automap_base(DeclBase)

class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'task'

    task_collection = relationship('Task', 
                                   secondary=task_task, 
                                   primaryjoin='Task.id==task_task.c.tid1',
                                   secondaryjoin='Task.id==task_task.c.tid2',
                                   backref='backward')

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///self.db")

Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

session = Session(engine)

task_0 = session.query(Task).filter_by(name ='task_0').first()
task_4 = session.query(Task).filter_by(name ='task_4').first()

print("task_0.task_collection = {}".format([x.name for x in task_0.task_collection]))
print("task_4.backward        = {}".format([x.name for x in task_4.backward]))
```

### Results

```
task_0.task_collection = ['task_1', 'task_2']
task_4.backward        = ['task_2', 'task_3']
```

### Using a Different Name

If you want to have a name other than `task_collection`, you need to use `automap`'s function for overriding collection-relationship names:

```
name_for_collection_relationship(base, local_cls, referred_cls, constraint)
```

The arguments `local_cls` and `referred_cls` are instances of the mapped table classes. For a self-referential, many-to-many relationship, these are both the same class. We can use the arguments to build a key that allows us to identify overrides.

Here is an example implementation of this approach.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base, name_for_collection_relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


DeclBase = declarative_base()

task_task = Table('task_task', DeclBase.metadata,
                  Column('tid1', Integer, ForeignKey('task.id')),
                  Column('tid2', Integer, ForeignKey('task.id')))

Base = automap_base(DeclBase)

class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'task'

    forward = relationship('Task', 
                           secondary=task_task, 
                           primaryjoin='Task.id==task_task.c.tid1',
                           secondaryjoin='Task.id==task_task.c.tid2',
                           backref='backward')


# A dictionary that maps relationship keys to a method name
OVERRIDES = {
    'Task_Task' : 'forward'
    }

def _name_for_collection_relationship(base, local_cls, referred_cls, constraint):

    # Build the key
    key = '{}_{}'.format(local_cls.__name__, referred_cls.__name__)

    # Did we have an override name?
    if key in OVERRIDES:
        # Yes, return it
        return OVERRIDES[key]

    # Default to the standard automap function
    return name_for_collection_relationship(base, local_cls, referred_cls, constraint)


engine = create_engine("sqlite:///self.db")

Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True, name_for_collection_relationship=_name_for_collection_relationship)
```

Note that the overriding of `name_for_collection_relationship` simply changes the name that `automap` uses for the relationship. In our case, the relationship is still being pre-defined by `Task`. But, the override tells `automap` to look for `forward` instead of `task_collection`, which it finds and therefore discontinues defining the relationship.

### Other Approaches Considered

Under some circumstances, it would be nice if we could override the relationship names without having to pre-define the actual relationship. On first consideration, this should be possible using `name_for_collection_relationship`. However, I could not get this approach to work for self-referential, many-to-many relationships, due to a combination of two reasons.

- `name_for_collection_relationship` and the related `generate_relationship` are called twice, once for each direction of the many-to-many relationship. In both cases, `local_cls` and `referred_cls` are the same, because of the self-referentiality. Moreover, the other arguments of `name_for_collection_relationship` are effectively equivalent. Therefore, we cannot, from the context of the function call, determine which direction we are overriding.
- Here is the even-more surprising part of the problem. It appears we cannot even count on one direction happening before the other. In other words, the two calls to `name_for_collection_relationship` and `generate_relationship` are very similar. The argument that actually determines the directionality of the relationship is `constraint`, which is one of the two foreign-key constraints for the relationship; these constraints are loaded, from `Base.metadata`, into a variable called `m2m_const`. Herein lies the problem. The order that the constraints end up in `m2m_const` is nondeterministic, i.e. sometimes it will be one order; other times it will be the opposite (at least when using `sqlite3`). Because of this, the directionality of the relationship is nondeterministic.

On the other hand, when we pre-define the relationship, the following arguments create the necessary determinism.

```
primaryjoin='Task.id==task_task.c.tid1',
secondaryjoin='Task.id==task_task.c.tid2',
```

Of particular note, I actually tried to create a solution that simply overrode the relationship names without pre-defining it. It exhibited the described nondeterminism.

### Final Thoughts

If you have a reasonable number of database tables that do not change often, I would suggest just using [Declarative Base](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many). It might be a little more work to set up, but it gives you more control.

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy reply; however one thing is that the python application can not modify the "structure" of the database. - It can read/write elements, however it cannot modify the database by adding/removing tables. (Or modifying metadata of the tables).
Another application "takes care" of that and is builds the leading ORM, python just has to follow.

Comment: The above implementation doesn't change any aspect of the underlying database. It changes the names of properties that are used to access the database, but those are wholly contained within python.